# I use Quick.db in my Discord bot. Every time I deploy an update the db does not save, why is this and how do I fix it?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-api

So... I use quick.db for my Discord bot's Economy System. It's all perfectly set up however every time I deploy an another update for my Discord bot from Github, the db does not save, and everyone's stats across everyone's server reset back to 0, why is this? Someone told me that it's because Heroku doesn't save "persistent" data, but I have hopes for a solution. Please let me know if there is any way to resolve this, and what the problem is, many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem on Heroku I don't think that Heroku doesn't save persistence data because my database can carry many users when they signed up on Heroku and that not works in else cases. just I'm following up the answers.

Comment: Oh, I see, but there is there any solution to it though?

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to answer this question. It's entirely dependent on where everything's stored, how it's stored and what the updates are

Comment: quick.db is based on sqlite3 which is a local database. Despite your `heroku-postgres` tag you are not using postgres. You need to use postgres however to have a persistent data storage on Heroku however.

Comment: @Joundill it's all stored through an sqlite file in my Github repository. I don't use an external-db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because Heroku Dyno Storage is "Ephemeral" which means that every day the db will be reset because it is taken again from your github or from where it's deploying